# Typescript, how to pass "Object is possibly null" error?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I've got the "Object is possibly null" error many times and usually I use a safety "if statement" in case it returns null.

I've got the following function:

```js
const ModalOverlay = (props: any[]) => {
  const overlayEl = useRef(null);
    useEffect(() => {
    overlayEl.current.focus();
    });
    return <div {...props} ref={overlayEl} />;
  }
```

But `overlayEl.current` gets the error "Object is not defined". So I've tried:

```js
if (!overlayEl) {
    return null
  } else {
    useEffect(() => {
    overlayEl.current.focus();
    });
    return <div {...props} ref={overlayEl} />;
  }
```

Which didn't work. I've tried also:

```js
overlay && overlayEl.current.focus();
```

Any hints would be highly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Hi, you should check for null before trying to call focus method
`if ( overlay && overlay.current ) { overlayEl.current.focus(); }`

Answer (score 192, accepted):

When you declare  const overlayEl = useRef(null);
Makes the type it comes out as is null because that's the best possible inference it can offer with that much information, give typescript more information and it will work as intended.

Try....

```
 const overlayEl = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
```

Alternatively some syntax sugar for if you don't care for when its undefined is to do something like this.

```
const overlayEl = useRef(document.createElement("div"))
```

using the above syntax all common DOM methods just return defaults such as "0" i.e overlayEl.offsetWidth, getBoundingClientRect etc.

Usage:

```
if(overlayEl.current) {
    // will be type HTMLDivElement NOT HTMLDivElement | null
    const whattype = overlayEl.current; 
}
```

The way this works is typescripts static analysis is smart enough to figure out that `if` check "guards" against null, and therefore it will remove that as a possible type from the union of `null | HTMLDivElement` within those brackets.

### == UPDATE 2023 ===

`document` and `window` based syntax sugar wont work in meta-frameworks such as NextJS and Remix where they often run their code outside the browser normally in Node where `document.` doesn't exist.

Comment: I think it's all important to mention that you also have to check for `null` before using `current`, as @thisismydesign pointed out.

Comment: Giving typescript more information was a good idea.

Comment: This did not work for me. Next.js app threw the error "document is undefined"

Comment: @Mark when this post was written meta frameworks like NextJS and Remix didn't exist; document is a browser-based API and only exists in the browser. Vanilla React runs in the browser and therefore it will always be available. In meta frameworks they often run React in non-browser based environments (Node) where document and window don't exist; Hence the error. In vanilla React this does indeed work.

I'll update the post to warn people using meta frameworks.

Comment: Now I get this error:
Cannot assign to 'current' because it is a read-only property.ts(2540)

const mapRef = React.useRef<L.Map>(null);

Comment: It does not work for me. In the code below, I have the word `files` underlined in red in the for statement,

`let files = this.import_file_element.files; if (files) { for (let file of files) {} }`

the error message is: 

'files' is possibly 'null'. ts(18047)

Answer (score 38):

```
const overlayEl = useRef() as MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
```

It will cast `overlayEl` to an initiated MutableRefObject that is the returning value of `useRef`:

```
function useRef<T = undefined>(): MutableRefObject<T | undefined>;
```

Yet in this case, the compiler will always think that `overlayEl` has a value.

Comment: Thank you. At least for me, this was the correct answer.

Note that if your element is an input you'll need to use `[...] = useRef() as MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement>`

Comment: Thanks, this one saved me. Other answers do not take into account cases like where you need to reassign .current

Comment: `document.createElement("div")` will get error on first render (error about document is undefiend)

Comment: @marzzy when this post was written meta frameworks like NextJS and Remix didn't exist; `document` is a browser-based API and only exists in the browser. Vanilla React runs in the browser and therefore it will always be available. In meta frameworks they often run React in non-browser based environments (Node) where `document` and `window` don't exist; Hence the error.

In vanilla React this does indeed work.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me to solve issue with ref for div element.

Answer (score 27):

Add a type to the ref as mentioned by @Shanon Jackson:

```
const linkRef = useRef<HTMLLinkElement>(null);
```

**And then**, make sure you check for `null` value before using `current`:

```
if (linkRef.current !== null) {
  linkRef.current.focus();
}
```

This will satisfy Typescript. Whereas either by itself wouldn't.

Using `any` or casting in order to "trick" the compiler defeats the purpose of using Typescript, don't do that.

Answer (score 11):

You can also use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) which is introduced in ES2020 instead of "if" statement  for cleaner code

```
const myRef = useRef<HTMLLinkElement>(null);

myRef.current?.focus();
```

You can check its browser support at [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining).

Answer (score 11):

I think this is more succinct than the other answers here:

```
const ModalOverlay = (props: any[]) => {
  const overlayEl = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    overlayEl.current!.focus();
  });
  return <div {...props} ref={overlayEl} />;
}
```

You specify the type of the reference, and you state you know it's not null.

Comment: Imo this is a better solution than the marked answer.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to "pass/skip" then this will do it `const overlayEl: any = useRef(null);`

Comment: _I just did ... and it passed!_ Doesn't sound like a good advice in general. In particular, casting to `any` jeopardises the purpose of having types - it makes `overlayEl` any type possible, so all the type information is lost. `any` type is like not type at all (vanilla js).

Comment: yes indeed, this is a workaround I've found just to make it working. I didn't said it's the way to go, or the best :)
As you can see, the question is "How to pass" which can indicate "How to skip", not how to fix...but that's another thing

Comment: it's really not good advice. you should avoid using `any` in typescript. you might as well be using javascript

Comment: yeah, I'm not a fan of any

Comment: Also works: const overlayEl = useRef(null as any);

Comment: @rosmcmahon Specifying a REST API schema might be the only case that makes sense. Making C++ reincarnation in JavaScript isn't for me.

Of course it is highly opinionated view of mine.

Comment: @KairatKempirbaev this title of this question is "Typescript, how to...".

Answer (score 7):

If you really know that in executing time you dont have a error here then just put :

```
 (overlayEl as any).current
```

If not, better use:

```
    if (typeof overlayEl !== 'undefined' &&
      typeof overlayEl.current !== 'undefined' &&
      overlayEl.current === null) {          
      return;
    }

    // Or

    try {
      // you code here ...
      // This is fine way to check by order -> parent.parent.FinalInstance
      // Also try & catch will handle all bad situation about current error
      overlay &&  overlayEl.current && overlayEl.current.focus();

    } catch(e){
       console.log("Real null >> ", e);     
    }

  // Suggest if i am wrong in syntax somewhere ,this is fast answer ;)
```

Comment: Unfortunately `typeof null` is equal to `object` and not to `"null"` and definitely not `null`.

Comment: I dont write this, it is from question. Maybe you are right.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to give no chance to typescript use this :

```
const iframe = useRef<HTMLIFrameElement | null>(null);

     if (
   typeof iframe !== "undefined" &&
   typeof iframe.current !== "undefined" &&
   iframe.current !== null
 ) {
   iframe?.current?.contentWindow='';
   );
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes we `useRef` not only to hold an element but a value like data. somehow when I check `if(something.current) return something.current` not working even if `i` add && `something.current!=null` so i found that:

`something.current!` which says to typescript `i` know there is a value and bypass this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you prefer but a nice syntax and structure might be to create an interface:

```typescript
interface divEL {
  current: HTMLDivElement | null;
}
```

This will keep your declaration clear and short and you can reuse the divEl interface for similar useRef hooks.

```typescript
const overlayEl: divEL = useRef(null);
```

Then add focus() like this:

```typescript
overlayEl.current!.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

for your useRef:

```
const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
```

and for input you can try this :

```
inputRef.current?.focus();
```

use "?" after current

Answer (score -3):

Best way is to use 'any' like below. The error will vanish

```
private someVariable: any;
```

Instead of specific types or object etc