# Angular - Error: Object is possibly null in password change validator

Tags: angular

I have this password change validator in Angular-12:

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';

export class OldPwdValidators {
  static shouldBe1234(control: AbstractControl) : Promise<ValidationErrors | null> {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        if(control.value !== '1234')
          resolve({ shouldBe1234: true });
        else
          resolve(null);
    });
  }

  static matchPwds(control: AbstractControl) {
    let newPwd2 = control.get('newPwd');
    let confirmPwd2 = control.get('confirmPwd');
    if(newPwd2.value !== confirmPwd2.value){
      return { pwdsDontMatch: true };
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

I got this error:

> Object is possibly null

and these two lines are highlighted:

> newPwd2.value

and

> confirmPwd2.value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript, how to pass "Object is possibly null" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677600/typescript-how-to-pass-object-is-possibly-null-error)

Comment: did you log this one `control.get('newPwd')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [AbstractControl get()](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#get),

> Returns: AbstractControl | null

Hence it is possible that `newPwd2` and `confirmPwd2` are `null`.

---

### SOLUTION 1

If you confirm that both `newPwd` and `confirmPwd` controls are (guarantee) existed, you can cast it to `AbstractControl`.

```js
let newPwd2: AbstractControl = control.get('newPwd') as AbstractControl;
let confirmPwd2: AbstractControl = control.get('confirmPwd') as AbstractControl;
```

[Solution 1 on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6x6epq?file=src/app/old-pwd.validators.ts)

---

### SOLUTION 2

Check both `newPwd` and `confirmPwd` must not be `null` and `undefined` before accessing its property.

```js
static matchPwds(control: AbstractControl) {
  let newPwd2 = control.get('newPwd');
  let confirmPwd2 = control.get('confirmPwd');

  if (newPwd2 && confirmPwd2) {
    if (newPwd2.value !== confirmPwd2.value) {
      return { pwdsDontMatch: true };
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

[Solution 2 on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dgrhkd?file=src/app/old-pwd.validators.ts)