# Validation Password and confirm passoword Ionic 7 and Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create a validation for 2 password fields, where one will only be accepted if the other is the same, all validations are coming out as expected, except the password validation in the 2 field created 'confirmpassword', which Could I be doing it wrong?

My ts file:

```
export class SignupPage implements OnInit {

  regForm: FormGroup;
  

  constructor(public formBuilder:FormBuilder,public loadingCtrl: LoadingController)   {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.regForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      fullname:['',[Validators.required]],
      email:['',[
        Validators.required,
        Validators.email,
        Validators.pattern("[a-z0-9._%+\-]+@[a-z0-9.\-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$")
      ]],
      password:['',[
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern("")]],
      confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required],
    } ,{ validator: this.passwordConfirming }  )
  }

  get errorControl(){
    return this.regForm?.controls;}
    
  async signUp(){
    const loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create();
    await loading.present();
    if(this.regForm?.valid){
      //const user = await this.authService.registerUser(email,password)
    }
  }
  passwordConfirming(group: FormGroup) {
    const password = group.get('password').value;
    const confirmPassword = group.get('confirmPassword').value;

    return password === confirmPassword ? null : { mismatch: true };
  }
}
```

and my HTML file:

```
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input formControlName="password" placeholder="Senha" class="input"></ion-input>
        <ion-icon name="lock-closed-outline"></ion-icon>
      </ion-item>
      <div *ngIf="this.regForm.controls?.['password'].touched && this.regForm.controls?.['password'].invalid">
        <ion-text *ngIf="this.errorControl.password.errors?.required">Insira uma Nova Senha!</ion-text>
        <ion-text *ngIf="this.errorControl.password.errors?.pattern">Insira uma Nova Senha Valida!</ion-text>
        
      </div>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-input  formControlName="confirmPassword" placeholder="Senha" class="input"></ion-input>
        <ion-icon name="lock-closed-outline"></ion-icon>
      </ion-item>
      <div *ngIf="this.regForm.controls?.['confirmPassword'].touched && this.regForm.controls?.['confirmPassword'].invalid" >
        <ion-text *ngIf="this.errorControl.confirmPassword.errors?.required">Confirme sua Senha!</ion-text>
        <ion-text *ngIf="this.errorControl.confirmPassword.errors?.invalid">Senhas nao coincidem</ion-text>
      </div>
```

I just want to validate that one password is the same as another

Comment: There are a few solutions regarding password & confirm password validation in reactive form, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68257830, https://stackoverflow.com/q/77247824, https://stackoverflow.com/q/77780364