# TS2721: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'null'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typescript-typings, react-typescript

TS2721: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'null'.

latestHandler.current(event) // TS2721: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'null'.

hover to latestHandler.current(event)
// const latestHandler: React.MutableRefObject<((event: MouseEvent) => void) | null>

I don't understand how to solve the type problem

I use a hook useLatest()

```
export const useLatest = <T>(value: T) => {
  const ref = useRef<T | null>(null)

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value
  }, [value])

  return ref
}
```

Next, I use it in

```
export const useOnClickOutside = <T extends HTMLElement = HTMLElement>(
  ref: RefObject<T>,
  handler: (event: MouseEvent) => void,
  attached = true
) => {
  const latestHandler = useLatest(handler)

  useEffect(() => {

    if (!attached) return

    const listener = (event: MouseEvent) => {
      if (!ref.current || ref.current.contains(event.target as Node)) {
        return
      }

      latestHandler.current(event)
    }
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', listener)
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousedown', listener)
    }
  }, [ref, latestHandler, attached])
}
```

I don't understand how to solve the type problem TS2721: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'null'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript, how to pass "Object is possibly null" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677600/typescript-how-to-pass-object-is-possibly-null-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `useLatest` hook the `ref` has an initial value of `null`, which causes `latestHandler` to have a type of `React.MutableRefObject<((event: MouseEvent) => void) | null>`. You either have to pass the default value to `useLatest` instead of assigning `null` as the value, or you can use optional chaining to call the function:

```
latestHandler.current?.(event);
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. In the wrong place, I put the operator ?